# JSON String in response shows up with quotes

Tags: rest-api

I use a REST Apex service and return String from the method. The client call to the REST API returns with qoutes around the reqult like this example: "...result.." and also with \" inside the result.How do I get rid of the quotes ? I saw Pat's blog about using Blob.valueOf(..) but I want to return a JSONObject like a String as you would do in Jersey.

```
@HttpGet
global static String getAllEmployeeDataForContact() { 
       return JSON.serialize(.....)
```

TIA

Comment: Have you tried setting the correct JSON headers?
RestResponse.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: Adding Content-Type helped but I thought by default all calls returned JSON but that doesn't seem to be true if I return String. Using Pat's Blob.valueoF with RestResponse.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); worked.

Comment: great to hear, perhaps best to mark metadaddy his anwser as correct and add the headers to it

Comment: @PJC I think what Vijay is actually trying to do is return an SObject or Apex Class object. I've updated my answer to give the correct method for doing both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes will come anyway, you don't need to use JSON.serialise with Apex web REST services, they take care of format XML/JSON automatically, so returning the type directly would work. Here is the sample, that I tried and is working fine.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/stacke/*')
global class SampleWebService {

    @httpget
    global static String getAllEmployeeDataForContact() { 
           return 'hello world';
    }

}
```

Result is coming with double quotes as you said and its correct as well

```
"hello world"
```

But this is not a JSON string actually try converting it to some wrapped type for easy consumption by clients like

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/stacke/*')
global class SampleWebService {

    global class Result {
        global String response{get;set;}
    }
    @httpget
    global static Result getAllEmployeeDataForContact() { 
            Result r = new Result();
            r.response = 'hello world';
           return r;
    }

}
```

This returns a JSON string like this

```
{
    "response": "hello world"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: .Awesome.Nice to learn this .

Answer (score 16):

To return a string without the quotes, set it as the response body:

```
@HttpGet
global static void sayHello() {
    RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // Return a single account as an example
    RestContext.response.responseBody = 
        Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize((Account)[SELECT Name, Id FROM Account LIMIT 1]));
}
```

Result:

```
$ curl -H "X-PrettyPrint: 1" https://superpat-developer-edition.na3.force.com/services/apexrest/superpat/HelloService
{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Account/0015000000f2cuKAAQ"},"Name":"Accounts R You","Id":"0015000000f2cuKAAQ"}
```

Having said that, there is a better way to return a JSON-encoded SObject or Apex Class object. Simply define the REST method to return the relevant type. For example, an SObject:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AccountService/*')
global class AccountService {
    @HttpGet
    global static Account getAccount() { 
        // return an account
        return [SELECT Name, Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```

Yielding

```
$ curl -H "X-PrettyPrint: 1" https://superpat-developer-edition.na3.force.com/services/apexrest/superpat/AccountService
{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Account/0015000000f2cuKAAQ"
  },
  "Name" : "Accounts R You",
  "Id" : "0015000000f2cuKAAQ"
}
```

or an Apex class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyService/*')
global class MyService {
    global class MyClass {
        public String s;
        public Integer i;

        public MyClass(String s, Integer i) {
            this.s = s;
            this.i = i;
        }
    }

    @HttpGet
    global static MyClass sayHello() { 
        MyClass obj = new MyClass('Hello', 1234);

        return obj;
    }
}
```

giving

```
$ curl -H "X-PrettyPrint: 1" https://superpat-developer-edition.na3.force.com/services/apexrest/superpat/MyService
{
  "s" : "Hello",
  "i" : 1234
}
```

Or even collections of either of the above:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AccountsService/*')
global class AccountsService {
    @HttpGet
    global static List<Account> getMatchingAccounts() {
        String prefix = RestContext.request.params.get('prefix');
        String filter = prefix + '%';
        return [SELECT Name, Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :filter];
    }
}

$ curl -H "X-PrettyPrint: 1" https://superpdeveloper-edition.na3.force.com/services/apexrest/superpat/HelloService?prefix=Unit
[ {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Account/0015000000VALDuAAP"
  },
  "Name" : "United Oil & Gas, UK",
  "Id" : "0015000000VALDuAAP"
}, {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Account/0015000000VALDvAAP"
  },
  "Name" : "United Oil & Gas, Singapore",
  "Id" : "0015000000VALDvAAP"
}, {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Account/0015000000VALE3AAP"
  },
  "Name" : "United Oil & Gas Corp.",
  "Id" : "0015000000VALE3AAP"
} ]
```

Comment: check comments on the question please

Comment: Checked comments on the question and expanded my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, Pat (@metadaddy) - exactly what I needed to know!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833992/apex-json-generator-writestring-escapes-quotes

It looks like it might solve your problem.