# JSON.serialise give output with escape charater

Tags: webservices, json, serialize, rest

I am doing this:

```
JSON.serialize(payload);
```

where payload is an object instance.

and getting this:

```
"{\"signup\":{\"salesforce_id\":\"003110022068XNz\",\"nationbuilder_id\":65536,\"last_name\":\"Downs\",\"first_name\":\"Danny\",\"email1\":\"persoxxxn@example.com\",\"do_not_call\":false,\"address\":{\"zip\":\"E12 6FF\",\"state\":null,\"fips\":null,\"county\":null,\"country_code\":null,\"country\":\"Great Britain\",\"city\":\"Norwich\",\"address3\":null,\"address2\":null,\"address1\":\"123 Fake St\"}},\"responseMessage\":\"OK - CONTACT UPDATED\"}"
```

I'd really rather not have to parse and remove all of the escape '\' backslashes. I am sure I have serialised JSON before without this issue?

I did try a straightforward replace('\',''); but this didnt have an effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution to a [similar problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/json-string-in-response-shows-up-with-quotes):

> To return a string without the quotes, set it as the response body:

```
RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(payload));
```

Comment: Thanks, can I get that out as a string though?

Comment: Thank... yes this works. My approach was wrong, my @HttpPost method was returning a string, which I was building. But with your approach is correct. I now return void, but set the responseBody as you describe.